# Group a record under a static type using sql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

StudentType

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hostel |
| 2 | Home |

Students

| ID | Name | studentTypeId | deletedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | 1 | null. |
| 2 | Second | 1 | 2022-02-07 |
| 3 | Third |  | null. |
| 4 | Fourth | 2 | null |
| 5 | Fifth | 2 | null |

So, I have two tables studentTypes and students. The student table could exist without the studentTypeId.

Using sql I want to be able to get the following json. The student with no id needs to be under unassigned type.

```
{
"studentTypes": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hostel",
        "students": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "First",
                "studentTypeId": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Home Going",
        "students": [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Fourth",
                "studentTypeId": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Fifth",
                "studentTypeId": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Unassigned",
        "students": [{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Third",
            "studentTypeId": null
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Second",
            "studentTypeId": 1
        }]
    }
]
```

}

I want the last type as Unassigned which will have students with no studentTypeId as well as which has deletedAt set. I cant figure-out how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unassigned student types can be included via a `UNION ALL`.
Then the students can be joined lateral via an [IS NOT DISTINCT FROM](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from).

If you want a pretty json, you could use the `jsonb_pretty` function.

> ```
> WITH CTE_STUDENTTYPES AS (
>   SELECT id, name
>   FROM StudentType
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT NULL, 'Unassigned'
> )
> SELECT 
> JSON_BUILD_OBJECT ('studentTypes', 
> JSON_AGG (
>   CASE WHEN t.ID IS NULL
>   THEN JSON_BUILD_OBJECT ('name', t.name, 'students', l.Students)
>   ELSE JSON_BUILD_OBJECT ('id', t.ID, 'name', t.name, 'students', l.Students)
>   END
> ))::json as StudentTypes
> FROM CTE_STUDENTTYPES t
> CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
>   SELECT JSON_AGG (
>        JSON_BUILD_OBJECT ('id', s.ID, 'name', s.name, 'studentTypeId', s.studentTypeId)
>   ) AS Students
>   FROM Students s
>   WHERE (CASE WHEN s.deletedAt IS NULL
>          THEN s.studentTypeId 
>          END) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM t.ID
> ) l;
> ```

> | studenttypes |
> | --- |
> | {"studentTypes" : [{"id" : 1, "name" : "Hostel", "students" : [{"id" : 1, "name" : "First", "studentTypeId" : 1}]}, {"id" : 2, "name" : "Home", "students" : [{"id" : 4, "name" : "Fourth", "studentTypeId" : 2}, {"id" : 5, "name" : "Fifth", "studentTypeId" : 2}]}, {"name" : "Unassigned", "students" : [{"id" : 3, "name" : "Third", "studentTypeId" : null}, {"id" : 2, "name" : "Second", "studentTypeId" : 1}]}]} |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=454acf6d889b41e290d6f0ec6f5e98da)*

Comment: Thank you so much, the sql works but I'm failing to include the students who has deletedAt as date to the UNASSIGNED type. I know the question didnt mention about it, but I'm trying to modify to get it but somehow I can't understand  where s.studentTypeId IS NOT DISTINCT FROM t.ID

Comment: @JyotiChhetri You can lookup `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` [here](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from). But it's basically just standard SQL for  an `=` that also matches null with null. Since `null = null` is normally undefined, neither true nor false.

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck with getting the students with deletedAt AS NOT NULL to the UNASSINGED Type along with studentTypeId AS NULL . I cant seem to figure out the solution, please can you help

Comment: @JyotiChhetri You can default it to null : `where case when s.deletedAt is null then s.studentTypeId end IS NOT DISTINCT FROM t.ID`

Comment: Hi I changed the question, I also defaulted it to null, but the s.deletedAt whose date are set is not grouped with the UNASSIGNED type

Comment: Second is under Unassigned in the json.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. :)